# Append new value to old value

Tags: python, django

Im trying to save value to a textfield in django with a celery task, but if the textfield has a value, I want to append the new value to the old value.

Here is my model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    info = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
 @shared_task
def update_profile(data, profile_username):
    
    #Get the profile
    profile = Profile.objects.get(username=profile_username) #(WORKING)
    
    #Check if info is in dataset
    if 'info' in data: #(WORKING)
        
        #Check if there is an old value
        if profile.info:  #(WORKING)
        
            #Old value found
            
            old_info = profile.info
            
            #Append old and new value
            new_info = '{}\n{}'format(old_info, data['info'])
            
            profile.info = new_info
  
        
        else:
            #No old value fond, save the new value
            profile.info = data['info'] #(WORKING)
    
    #Save profile
    profile.save() #(WORKING)
```

If the field does not have an old value, I can save the new value just fine, but when I try save the old and new value together, I will not work! I can only save one of them, not "update" the field like I want to.

## Edit:

I see now that `new_info = '{}\n{}'format(old_info, data['info'])` is working, but I get this error : `UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'Test\xf8', 128, 129, 'ordinal not in range(128)')`

Comment: Does this line `profile = Profile.objects.get(profile=profile)` really get the profile? `Profile` does not have a attribute called `profile`.

Comment: Yes, it does. Updated the question code now, so it is more clear.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious option: `profile.info = '{}\n{}'.format(profile.info, data['info'])` ?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Tried it now, but I still only get the old value.

Comment: Get rid of your if loop - immediately after you get the profile, type `profile.info = '{}\n{}'.format(profile.info, data.get('info',''))` then followed by `profile.save()`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Your suggestion to `use profile.info = '{}\n{}'.format(profile.info, data['info'])` worked. Put it in answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simplify the loop, so that you can debug it correctly.  Use `get` (a method of dictionaries) to fetch the key, and you can assign it a default value if the key doesn't exist.

Putting this together, your code now is:

```
def update_profile(data, profile_username):

    profile = Profile.objects.get(username=profile_username) #(WORKING)
    profile.info = u'{}\n{}'.format(profile.info, data.get('info', '').encode('utf-8'))
    profile.save()
```